# How to get a list of cms pages in Magento?

Tags: magento

**What i'm trying todo**

I have created an admin form where the user needs to select a CMS page from a drop down.

**What i have tried**

```
$form->addField('cms_page_id', 'select', array(
'label'     => Mage::helper('custom/data')->__('CMS Page'),
'class'     => 'required-entry',
'required'  => true,
'name'      => 'cms_page_id',
'values'    => Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->toOptionArray(),
'value'     => $this->getCmsPageId()
));
```

The idea is the code gets the an option array from the CMS model. However "toOptionArray" is an invalid function for the 'cms/page' model.

**My Question**

How can I get an option array of CMS pages for use in an admin form in Magento?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

With your code you are loading a new cms page model. To get a collection use following code and `toOptionArray()` will at least return something:

```
Mage::getModel('cms/page')->getCollection()->toOptionArray()
```

Answer (score 1):

CMS Pages array with Links

```
$cms_arr = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->getCollection()->toOptionArray();   
$cms_pages[""] = "-Select CMS Page-"; 
foreach($cms_arr as $cms){ 
    $url = $this->getUrl($cms["value"]); 
    $cms_pages[$url] = $cms["label"]; 
}
```