# How do I add links to the top menu in Magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I want to modify the top level menu using code. I want it to a show list of pages in top level. How is it possible?

Comment: you can get the collection of pages : https://stackoverflow.com/a/17379955/5635098

Answer (score 0):

You can modify this file '`\app\design\frontend\yourtheme\template\page\html\topmenu.phtml`' and add custom code there to show list of pages.

Answer (score 0):

```
`<reference name="top.links">
        <block type="checkout/links" name="checkout_cart_link">
            <action method="addCartLink"></action>
            <action method="addCheckoutLink"></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
```

Comment: add it in page.xml file to apply in whole website